# About the relationship between non-termination and inconsistency?

Tags: formal-languages, functional-programming

I've been trying to get into Agda and I noticed that it doesn't have recursion, which implies that it isn't *Turing-Complete*.

From what I could understand, **if** Agda had *recursion*, it would make itself an *inconsistency* from a type theory perspective.

Something stuck to my mind: **Is it possible to exist a language that it isn't strongly normalizing but, yet, consistent?** Or does the **existence** of recursion *mandatorily* implies inconsistency?

Comment: Forcibly add a reduction rule $t \to t$, and normalization is lost, but all the logical properties are preserved :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, chi. However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it, would it be possible for you to expand your answer a little?

Comment: Done. I don't think my answer will be really satisfactory, but at least it points out a few trivial cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Some trivial type systems

Let the set of types be $\bot,\top$ and the sets of terms be $a,b$, with typing rules

$$
\vdash a:\top \qquad \vdash b:\top
$$
and computational rules
$$
a \to b \qquad b \to a
$$

Then, the resulting system has no (weakly/strongly) normalizing terms, yet it is consistent since no term inhabits $\bot$.

We can also allow recursion on $\top$, if we want.

$$
\dfrac{
\Gamma, x:\top \vdash e:\top
}{
\Gamma \vdash {\sf rec}\ x. e\ :\top
}
$$
with the obvious computational rule
$$
{\sf rec}\ x. e \to e\{{\sf rec}\ x. e/x\}
$$

## On adding full recursion

Of course, we can't allow unrestricted recursion on $\bot$, otherwise ${\sf rec}\ x.x:\bot$ leads to an inconsistency.

## Adapting more serious type systems

If we take any strongly normalizing typed lambda calculus, we can modify the computational rules to add a silly reduction step
$$
t\to t
$$
for any term $t$.

The new calculus has as inhabited types the same inhabited types, so it preserves consistency. The calculus is not even weakly normalizing, though.

Comment: That was extremely useful! Since there are so many simple ways of adding non-normalized terms without leading to an inconsistency, why is it such a big deal for Agda? Is there an explanation for the cause of this problem?

Comment: @TiagoLoriatoSimoes With a powerful calculus like Agda, without normalization it can be hard to prove consistency. The $t\to t$ rule above is simple to handle, but adding a constrained form of non-always-terminating recursion can be vastly more complex. Also, it is nice to know that when you prove in Agda that there is some natural satisfying some property, you get for free a _terminating_ program which produces said natural. That's one of the main features of constructivism, and people don't want to break that.

Comment: I think your trivial type system might be too trivial. In particular, usually recursion principles allow an arbitrary target type, and you have suggested here that avoiding recursion into bottom solves the problem, but this only works because there are only two types and we know which ones are supposed to be inhabited. In any reasonable type system with empty types, it is not decidable to determine if a type is empty, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I agree. Still, showing some some trivial counterexample helps as well. Indeed, adding non-terminating recursion on general types is vastly more complex, as I wrote above. To sketch a non-trivial example, one should be able to add a restricted fixed point function $fix:\ \forall A.\ A \to (A\to A)\to A$ such that $fix\ x\ f$ evaluates to the least fixed point of $f$ (potentially a non terminating computation), provided that $x$ inhabits $A$. This should preserve consistency, I guess, but it breaks the type system in other unwanted ways.

Comment: @chi You have to be careful with that kind of $\mathrm{fix}$: taking $n=\mathrm{fix}\ \mathrm{nat}\ 0\ S$, with the appropriate computational rules on $\mathrm{fix}$, you should be able to prove $n=S\ n$, which implies a contradiction! It isn't enough to restrict fixed points to inhabited types: they must also have a consistent semantics. In Agda, natural numbers are *definite*, i.e. they must have a precisely defined value in terms of the constructors.

Comment: @cody Thank you, that's a good point! I'm curious, now: what if we further restrict it to functions which admit at least a fixed point?

Comment: @chi that would work, but how would it lead to a non-terminating system?

Comment: @cody $({\sf fix}\ A\ p\ f) \to f({\sf fix}\ A\ p\ f) \to f(f({\sf fix}\ A\ p\ f)) \cdots $ where $p$ is the proof of "$f$ has a fixpoint". This might be weakly normalizing (e.g. if $f=\lambda x.c$) or not even weakly (e.g. if $f=\lambda x.x$). Would this work?

Comment: @chi yes, I believe that this would work.

Comment: @cody How would you prove a contradiction from that? Notwithstanding a violation of the Peano axioms, this is consistent with the natural numbers as appearing in say Haskell (as a coinductive type). In order to prove a contradiction you would want to define a function to bottom that uses this proof, but this would be a dependent $fix$, which is not available in chi's example.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The point is, in Agda using a inductive naturals type $\sf nat$, you can prove $\forall x:{\sf nat}.\ x\neq S x$. This copes with the counterexample by cody: $x={\sf fix\ nat\ 0}\ S : {\sf nat}$

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, if you have only simple types, then adding any term which has as a type a theorem of propositional logic will not provoke inconsistency, unsurprisingly.

Comment: @chi Although the proof carrying ${\sf fix}$ does not cause any inconsistencies, I believe it proves the axiom of choice, i.e. it is nonconstructive. If $A$ is a nonempty type, then there exists a fixpoint of the identity, so ${\sf fix}\;A\;p\;{\sf id}:A$ is a "chosen" element of $A$. The reason this doesn't accord with the computational behavior of ${\sf fix}$ is because if you start running ${\sf fix}$ from some random element you may not make it to a fixpoint even if they exist, e.g. ${\sf some}\;n\mapsto{\sf some}\;(n+1)$, ${\sf none}\mapsto{\sf none}$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Keep in mind that $p$ proves that there is a fixed point, so it is a dependent pair $p=\langle a:A , h: a=f a\rangle$. So we have to provide an inhabitant of $A$ inside $p$.

Comment: @chi I'm not familiar with Agda specifically, but if this pair lives in a proof irrelevant universe then it's AC, and if it doesn't then $fix$ has a trivial implementation (unwrap the pair), except that if it has a computation rule then you have "upgraded" a propositional equality to a definitional one, and you can probably use this to prove equality reflection.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Indeed we could implement $fix$ with a trivial implementation, but its computational rule instead computes otherwise, breaking normalization in some cases.